# Remove NSWindow from array after closing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I'm creating windows programmatically and then adding them to an array when I show them like this.

```
NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
window.delegate = self;
window.releasedWhenClosed = YES;    
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
[_array addObject:window];
```

I need to remove the windows from the array when they are closed but I can't seem to get this to work.  If I remove the window from my array in the `-windowWillClose:` delegate method like this my app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` after the delegate method completes.

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSWindow *window = notification.object;
    [_array removeObject:window];
}
```

Comment: Show. Your. Code. Thanks!

Comment: Also: do you really think it's wise to keep a strong reference to a major object like an NSWindow that doesn't belong to you? Why do you need to do that? The app knows what windows there are; what's this array even for?

Comment: Ok, I added code.  If I don't keep a strong reference the window won't show.  Also depending on the user action it will show an existing window instead of creating a new one.

Comment: "If I don't keep a strong reference the window won't show" Really? So you're not using NSWindowControllers?

Comment: Thanks for your comments!  Creating a window controller for the window and storing those in the array solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an NSWindowController for the NSWindow and storing those controllers in the array (`NSMutableArray<NSWindowController *>`) instead of windows solves the problem.

```
NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
window.delegate = self; 
NSWindowController *windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindow:window];
[windowController showWindow:self];
[_array addObject:windowController];
```

NSWindowDelegate

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSWindow *window = notification.object;
    [_array removeObject:window.windowController];
}
```

Comment: Great! I think I oversight your code that you are storing `NSWindow`. I always thought you are storing `NSWindowController` and that is what I referred in my answer.

Comment: Note that `releasedWhenClosed` is ignored for a window which is controlled by a window controller. There's no point setting it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I removed that line.

Answer (score 5):

Set the window's `releasedWhenClosed` property to false, not true.

Setting that property to true essentially causes an extra release beyond what normal memory management would involve. If you're using ARC, then this is one release too many because ARC itself would do balanced retains and releases. (If you were not using ARC, then that release would be appropriate to balance the `+alloc` in your first code snippet which is otherwise not balanced. However, even in that case, I'd recommend writing code that does normal, balanced memory management and setting this property to false.)

Second, set the window's `delegate` property to `nil` before removing it from the array.

Finally, if that doesn't fix the issue, show the details of the crash, including the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  This still caused a crash but I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe window controller will be deallocated by ARC in the middle of `windowWillClose:`. Try with `windowShouldClose:` instead.

Comment: It still crashes using this method.

Comment: I see. I think you might want to follow [this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/116358-releasing-nswindowcontroller-when-the-window-closes.html) for another alternative.